# How to get each button to flash using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm very new to jQuery and to learn it better I'm working on a Simon game. I'm trying to Use jQuery to select the button with the same id as the `randomChosenColor`. I'm only getting one button(red) to flash on click and I don't know where I'm going wrong. Result should be on click the button will click to the matching id color.

```js
let buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
let gamePattern = [];

function nextSequence() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

  let randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);

  $("#" + randomChosenColour).on("click", function() {
    $("#" + randomChosenColour).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  })

  return randomChosenColour;
}

nextSequence();
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div lass="row">
    <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">
    </div>
    <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">
    </div>
    <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's doing exactly what you programmed it to do. it selects a random color and blinks if you click on it. it's not always red either. it's unclear what you want it to do.

Comment: No I'm not trying to use CSS.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Weird on my end is only the red button working.

Comment: not with this code. the code isn't going to just magically operate differently on your machine. if this is the code you're using then all your buttons "work" assuming this is what you wanted them to do.

Comment: This is so funny I am also doing the same udemy course and I am stuck there

Answer (score 1):

You get only 1 button clickable, because every click triggers the same action and your function had already chosen the number and color.
If you want it to make another button clickable, just refresh your page. Do it a few times if the red button will randomly be chosen still.

Anyway the answer to your hesitation "select the button with the same id as the randomChosenColor" - your code does exactly what you want. You can check it by adding 1 line at the end (below). Now the page alerts you about the color and this exactly same color button is clickable:

```
let buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
let gamePattern = [];

function nextSequence() {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

    let randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);

    $("#" + randomChosenColour).on("click", function() {
        $("#" + randomChosenColour).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    })

    return randomChosenColour;
}

alert(nextSequence());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use my code. Here if you click on any button it will flash. Also if you call function `nextSequence()` then random button will flash.

```js
let buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
let gamePattern = [];
let userClickedPattern = [];

$(".btn").on("click", function() { 
    let userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
    userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);
    $("#" + userChosenColour).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
});

function nextSequence() {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    let randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);
    $("#" + randomChosenColour).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin:  5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;

}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="game5.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```